# Replace &#039 with ' in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, html-encode

I have a javascript variable that fills with Laravel translation system:

```
'are_you_sure' => '¿Remplacer l\'arbre?',
```

and then in JS:

```
swal({
          title: "{{ trans('msg.are_you_sure') }}",
          ...

    });
```

And it appears to me:

`¿Remplacer l&#039;arbre?`

EDIT:

Sorry for `htmlspecialchars`, the thing is it doesn't change removing `htmlspecialchars`, adding it, or adding `htmlspecialchars_decode`

Comment: Uhm… `htmlspecialchars` is what turns `'` into `&#039`… Simply… *don't do that!?*

Comment: Do you know what `htmlspecialchars` is doing? It's exactly that, turning `'` into `&#39;`

Comment: check edit, it doesn't work in any case... :(

Answer (score 1):

`htmlspecialchars` takes a plain text string and turns it into HTML.

i.e. exactly the opposite of what you want it to do

Look at [`htmlspecialchars_decode`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars_decode) instead.

Beware `"` and new line characters which will break the JS syntax.

Answer (score 1):

`htmlspecialchars()` is what is causing your `'` to turn into the html translation(&#039). Just removing it should do the trick.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 1):

I finally found it. I had to replace `{{ }}` by `{!! !!}`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this worked for me:

```
use {{ 'key' |trans |e('js') }}
```

Source: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/escape.html

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use unescape() Function to convert the code into a string, i left you a web here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp

Comment: `unescape` is (a) deprecated due to broken unicode support and should not be used and (b) unescapes the wrong kind of escaping for this problem

Comment: W3Schools are [much better than they once were](http://www.w3fools.com/) which means they are no worse that *awful*. You should avoid recommending them.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin for the advice.

Comment: @quentin But if you read in the same line where it says 
The unescape() function was deprecated in JavaScript version 1.5. You have the answer to.

Use decodeURI() or decodeURIComponent() instead.